# Alternative way of saying "allows us to...."

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

What are some alternative ways of expressing the following?

> This fact allows us to focus our attention on XYZ.

I keep writing "allows us to..." over and over, unable to think of another way of writing this.

Comment: _Thanks to this (fact) / Because of this, we can focus..._ ?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that pops into my head is **[lets](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20lets)**:

> not prevent or forbid; allow.
>
> *"my boss let me leave early"*
>
> **synonyms:** allow to, permit to, give permission to, give leave to, authorize to, sanction to, grant the right to, license to, empower to,
>   enable to, entitle to
>
> *"let him sleep for now"*

"This fact lets us focus our attention on XYZ."

You also might just want to do a synonym search of "allow" and go from there. Your question is pretty much exactly why we use a thesaurus.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix that sentence is to just cut it out.

It makes perfect since to say, "This fact [focuses] our attention on XYZ."

You could also say "Lets us"...

If you really feel like you have to use something like that there are plenty of synonyms or other ways to say it.

I could list them all, but that would take forever. So instead check out: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/allows